# Convert pivot tables to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a pivot table, for example,

```
first second                    
bar   one  
      two    
foo   one  
      two
```

How do I change it back to a normal dataframe with all values and rows and column filled?

```
first second                    
bar   one 
bar   two  
foo   one 
bar   two
```

Answer (score 4):

if **table** is the name of your pivottable and **df** is the new dataframe,

```
df = table.reset_index()
```