# Pandas pivot table to dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a pivot table (pt) that looks like this:

```
+---------+------------+-------+----+
|         | ZY         | z     |  y |  
+---------+------------+-------+----+
| period_s| ZONE       |       |    | 
+---------+------------+-------+----+
| 201901  | A          | 14    | 34 |
|         | B          | 232   | 9  |
|         | C          | 12    | 2  |
+---------+------------+-------+----+
| 201902  | A          | 196   | 70 |
|         | K          | 10    | 1  |
|         | D          | 313   | 99 |
+---------+------------+-------+----+
```

which came from a dataframe (df) using the following code:

```
pt=df.pivot_table(index=['period_s','ZONE'], columns='ZY', values='ID', aggfunc="count")
```

where the ZY field has two classes z and y.

I tried using the

```
df = table.reset_index()
```

also

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0) #remove amount
df.columns.name = None               #remove categories
df = df.reset_index()
```

As mentioned here [transform pandas pivot table to regular dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756052/transform-pandas-pivot-table-to-regular-dataframe) and like this one [Convert pivot tables to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46733872/convert-pivot-tables-to-dataframe)

I want to have a dataframe like this:

```
+---------+-------+------------+----------+
| period_s| ZONE  |    z       | y        |
+---------+-------+------------+----------+
|  201901 |     A | 14         |       34 |
|  201901 |     B | 232        |        9 |
|  201901 |     C | 12         |        2 |
|  201902 |     A | 196        |       70 |
|  201902 |     K | 10         |        1 |
|  201902 |     D | 313        |       99 |
+---------+-------+------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit late but I think getting rid of `pt.columns.name` (i.e. `"ZY"`) and resetting index would return the expected output. A method chain (`set_axis()` or `rename_axis()` to get rid of `columns.name` and `reset_index()` to convert `period_s` and `ZONE` into columns).

```py
pt.set_axis(pt.columns.tolist(), axis=1).reset_index()
#pt.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
```

A more straightforward way is to `reset_index()` and remove `columns.name` explicitly.

```py
pt.reset_index(inplace=True)
pt.columns.name = None
```

---

A reproducible example:

```py
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'period_s': np.random.choice([201901, 201902], size=100),
                   'ZONE': np.random.choice([*'ABC'], size=100),
                   'ZY': np.random.choice([*'zy'], size=100),
                   'ID': np.arange(100)})
pt = df.pivot_table(index=['period_s','ZONE'], columns='ZY', values='ID', aggfunc="count")

# output
pt.set_axis(pt.columns.tolist(), axis=1).reset_index()
```

[image: result]